# An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in AnyStore1.exe

Tags: c#, sql-server-2014-express

project execute successfully, but when i click on purchase or sales option of my project then project suddenly crashes and error occurs.i want to save all the the transection entered through save button into the database.
i'm new in c# so please help
[image: transection detail dal code]

```
    transectionsDAL tdal = new transectionsDAL();
    transectionDetailDAL tdDAL = new transectionDetailDAL();
    using(TransactionScope scope=new TransactionScope())
        {
            int transactionID = -1;
            bool w = tdal.Insert_Transection(transection,out transactionID);
            for(int i = 0; i < transectiondt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                transectionDetailBLL transactiondetail = new transectionDetailBLL();
                string productname = transectiondt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
                productsBLL p = pdal.GetproductIDFromName(productname);

                transactiondetail.product_id = p.id;
                transactiondetail.rate = decimal.Parse(transectiondt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
                transactiondetail.qty = decimal.Parse(transectiondt.Rows[i][2].ToString());
                transactiondetail.total = Math.Round(decimal.Parse(transectiondt.Rows[i][3].ToString()),2);
                transactiondetail.dea_cust_id = dc.id;
                transactiondetail.added_date = DateTime.Now;
                transactiondetail.dea_cust_id = u.id;
                bool y = tdDAL.InsertTransectionDetail(transactiondetail);
                success = w && y;
```

Comment: TypeInitializationException means something went wrong in a static constructor, and I don't see any constructor code, only unrelated business logic

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto not in a constructor, but in a type initializer ("static constructor") or the initialization of static fields.

Comment: Could you please post the full exception details? You might have to look in the Windows event log to see it if you don't catch and log exceptions in your code.

Comment: Can you share the code of `transectionDetailDAL` class?

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya. how i can paste my code here? code is too long and comment can't give more space.

Answer (score 1):

At first check the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.typeinitializationexception?view=netcore-3.1

> The exception that is thrown as a wrapper around the exception thrown by the class initializer.

That means it's either one of the deals

```
transectionsDAL tdal = new transectionsDAL();
transectionDetailDAL tdDAL = new transectionDetailDAL();
```

Or the bll

```
transectionDetailBLL transactiondetail = new transectionDetailBLL();
```

It could also be inside one of your functions

To get to the real problem, you need to inspect the real reason which is in the `InnerException` field.

> When a class initializer fails to initialize a type, a TypeInitializationException is created and passed a reference to the exception thrown by the type's class initializer. The InnerException property of TypeInitializationException holds the underlying exception.

My suggestion for you to get the real exception would be to wrap with

```
try {
    /// your code here
}
catch (TypeInitializationException e) {
    throw e.InnerException;
}
```

Even better, debug your code line by line to see where the problem is.

Comment: enen by using this catch (TypeInitializationException e)  error could not resolve

Comment: Try catch will not resolve the issue. It will help you to find your the cause of the issue.

Comment: You need to get the message of `e.InnerException` and share in the question. That will help us to identify the issue in the code so that we can suggest how to solve the issue.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in AnyStore1.exe